# Why 'Add what you're doing or feeling' option/icon is missing from my Android Facebook app? How should I enable it?

Tags: facebook

I'm using Sony Xperia C Android smartphone.
Facebook app is pre-installed in it.

The issue I'm faing is I'm not getting an option for 'Add what you're doing or feeling' when I want to update my status. Only three options are there as follows :

1. Tag people in your post
2. Add a location to post
3. Add photos to your post

The missing one is'Add what you're doing or feeling'. I checked all the settings but no success.

The same option appears on facebook website. Can someone please help me in this regard?

Thanks.

If you want any other information please do let me know.

Comment: What version of facebook are you running?

Comment: @Manubhargav : I'm running Facebook Version 2.3

Comment: My facebook version is `41.0.0.25.131` . I don't see this problem.

Comment: Update your Facebook app, you'll probably get those options

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facebook released v2.3 around 20th March 2013, Here's a [snapshot of the page with Facebookv2.3](http://web.archive.org/web/20130325030807/https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana&hl=en).

Facebook announced it's [enhanced status update](http://www.adweek.com/socialtimes/status-updates-to-share-what-youre-doing-or-feeling-will-roll-out-to-all-u-s-facebook-users-in-coming-weeks/292284) on how they're feeling around 10th April 2013 which is the reason it's not included in the App.

Update the app, you'll get this feature.

Comment: Thanks for your interest in the issue. Can you please tell me how should I update my facebook app since nowhere I'm getting update option.

Comment: Go to play store > My apps > Installed > Check for facebook app, see if it's there